# android build errer: BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at external/webkit/WebCore/dom/make_names.pl line 38

Tags: android, build, android-sdk-2.3

I get an android build error, when I compile android 2.3.4 with fedora 16. (compiling android 2.2.1 on the same machine works perfectly.)

error message:

```
(..)
Install: out/target/product/generic/system/lib/libttspico.so
Install: out/target/product/generic/system/lib/libttssynthproxy.so
target Generated: libwebcore <= external/webkit/WebCore/dom/make_names.pl
Can't locate Switch.pm in @INC (@INC contains: external/webkit/WebCore/bindings/scripts /usr/local/lib64/perl5 /usr/local/share/perl5 /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/lib64/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 .) at external/webkit/WebCore/dom/make_names.pl line 38.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at external/webkit/WebCore/dom/make_names.pl line 38.
make: *** [out/target/product/generic/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libwebcore_intermediates/WebCore/HTMLNames.h] Fehler 2
```

What is wrong here?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a problem related to Perl. The package **Switch.pm** is no longer present in Fedora 16 Perl version. You need to install this package.

Comment: Thanks. I've downgraded perl to releasever 15 and everything worked again :-)

Answer (score 3):

If you're building on Fedora 16, you will need to add **Switch.pm** via yum:

```
yum install perl-Switch
```

Comment: Thanks. Why isn't switch included in current perl anymore?